# How do I fix PHP module thread-safe/non-thread-safe mismatch?

Tags: php, winapi, php-extension

This is out of the error log:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: BOPEE Extension: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: CustomExt Module: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

How I get the non-threadsafe source for PHP? The only download link I found on windows.php.net/download was http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.2-src.zip and that appears to be the threadsafe code --- or is there some way of telling the source  that it's actually non-threadsafe?

I have tried putting `--disable-zts` on the commandline for `configure.bat` but whilst that has a good effect on the outputs from `configure.bat`, it doesn't seem to make the source any less threadsafe.

Answer (score 7):

In your case above, PHP itself is non-thread-safe (NTS), but the module is thread-safe (TS). The module is thread-safe because the Zend Thread-Safe `ZTS` constant is defined (either in the module's source code or in VS 2008's Preprocessor Definitions).

Simply changing `ZTS=1` to `ZTS=0` does *not* work.
**You must completely remove the definition of `ZTS`.**