# Connecting to DB2 with PHP via Apache on AIX7.1

Tags: php, apache, db2, aix, httpd.conf

I am trying to understand what do this message mean! I have tried googling it but could not find anything much helpful.

I am trying to include 2 php extensions, `db2_ibm.so` and `pdo_ibm.so`, in the `php.ini` (I have edited that php.ini file which was shown in `<?php phpinfo() ?>`).

In the PHP cli version, using the command `php -m`, I can see that the modules are being rightly loaded. I can see the versions ibm_db2 1.9.1 and pdo_ibm 1.3.2

However, when I try to do the same via Apache it would not connect. I moved on and looked at the Apache error logs and found the following.

For db2_ibm.so, I got the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/opt/freeware/lib/php/modules/ibm_db2_5.2.1.so'
- rtld: 0712-001 Symbol executor_globals was referenced 
from module /opt/freeware/lib/php/modules/ibm_db2_5.2.1.so(), 
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.
in Unknown on line 0
```

And for pdo_ibm.so:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_ibm: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
```

I can understand that there is some problem with defining PATH but not sure how to go about the problem.

Following Versions are installed on my system (AIX 7.1):

- PHP 5.2.17
- Apache 2.2.16
- DB2 9.7.4

I have installed Apache and PHP them from RPM packages.

[The reason why I was going for the older versions of PHP and Apache is because of the fact that the extension files `ibm_db2.so` and `pdo_ibm.so` that were found with DB2 Client were compatible only with the lower versions of PHP.]

Please do suggest some solution soon as I am stuck here for days now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Find the pid for Apache's httpd process:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

You will likely see a set of them.  In my case, one has a parent of init (1) and the others have the parent of the first.  I would pick the one with the parent of init but for educational purposes you might want to pick all of them.  Then do:

```
ps eww <pid>
```

where pid is one of the process ids (2nd column) of the first ps.  (The parent process id is the third column.)

That command displays the environment for Apache.  Then do the same for your shell by doing:

```
ps eww $$
```

Hopefully you will discover a difference that makes sense.  What I would do is muck with the shell's environment and run php -m until you get the error that is happening to Apache.  That will give you what specifically is in Apache's environment that is causing the problems.  Then use Apache's commands to correct the environment.

All this is for the simple case where you can see a difference in the environment using ps and track down a difference and are able to correct it.  In more stubborn cases, you will need to "wrap" php.  In fact, you might find this approach easier.

I don't know the details but Apapche is kicking off php somewhere somehow.  Lets pretend it is calling /some/specific/path/php with various arguments.

Create a directory: /some/specific/path/.orig
Move php into .orig
Create a shell script (be sure to do chmod +x on it) and in the script do something such as:

```
#!/bin/ksh
date >> /tmp/php.log
env >> /tmp/php.log
echo "args = $@" >> tmp/php.log
exec /some/specific/path/.orig/php "$@"
```

Put that script as /some/specific/path/php

You can add more debugging to the script as you need to.  You first want to see if you can really execute the same command that Apache is doing from the command line.  So dig out the arguments from the log file and execute that same command.  You might need to substitute various pieces of the command.  This step might be too hard and not worth it but from the error I'm worried that it is not really a difference between Apache and your shell environments but something really isn't set up right.  Getting the exact same command to execute from the shell will prove that it is a difference in the shell and Apache environments.

Then, as in the first style of debugging, track down what is different in the two environments.  The debugging script can even "fix" it before doing the exec as a temporary solution.

If you remember, please post back what you find out as a comment.  I'm curious what is causing this error.

As usual...

good luck!

Comment: Also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271798/how-do-i-fix-php-module-thread-safe-non-thread-safe-mismatch ... it won't really help but it appears one of your modules needs to be recompiled.  I suppose it still could be an environment where one method is picking up one set of libraries and the other is picking up another set... maybe...

Comment: I have tried the first option, i.e. making the `PATH` same for both Apache and shell and see if `php -m` gives something similar to Apache errors. Guess what! nothing changed. Now I am not able to find the /some/specific/path/php.

Is there some command to look for that? I am still searching. Thank you

Comment: Is it the path to libphp5.so module?

Comment: Oh.  I bet it is and wrapping it isn't going to work. Sorry.  is LIBPATH set and is it the same in either case?  That is much more important in this situation than PATH is.

Comment: Another suggestion: see if the guy(s) at perzl.org (which I assume you got all these packages) can help.  You might also see if db2 has a threaded version (or thread safe version) of their libraries.  As I said, I'm thinking this is not a path problem but the simple php -m is not doing the same thing as what Apache is doing.

Comment: I don't see any LIBPATH for both apache as well as shell using those commands. Although I have made sure whatever LIBPATH is required for Apache and DB2 must load before `apachectl restart`